# Specify how to function as 'other' in operation (Python)

Tags: python

I'm working on a custom class for an object in Python which has a string representation and an integer interpretation. The string representation is calculated from the integer one and vice versa. An object from this class is supposed to 'interact' with integers with operations (like + etc). So I've overwritten all the operators in my custom class, so they can interact with integers. Now, everything works fine when my class is to the left of the operand, but when my class is to the right and an integer is to the left, the operation fails because e.g. the 'add' method from int requires another int to the right of an operand. How can I fix this? I've thought of subclassing my class from int, but this could make things complicated so I'm curious if there's a simple solution to this.

Comment: Did you do `__radd__`?

Comment: No! Just looked up and saw there is a 'r' version for every operation. Thanks a lot, guess this will fix it!

Comment: Here are some docs to get you started: https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#operators See "Reflected arithmetic operators"